# Letters Bleeding White

Tags: css, fonts

I'm using a couple Google fonts (Roboto & Tinos) for my website. I have an odd problem with the display of the fonts. Text on a light background are fine. But on uses where there is a dark box the text appears with white areas. [This is a link](https://www.msholmes.org/cemeteries) to a good example.

TIA for any assistance provided!
jdadwilson

Comment: Please include everything needed in your question - I for one am not going to click on an external link...

Answer (score 0):

Don't really understand question, more information is needed. Use browser's developer mode to check CSS properties, you may find out that something is overwriting color. Sometimes may use:

```
div {
 color: black !important;
}
```

But again without you providing more information it is impossible to answer your question.

Comment: I would add a screen shot but can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: If the question cannot be understood, do not answer it. He didn't supply his markup here which makes it "off topic". Do not answer off topic questions. [answer]

Comment: I understand, will not happen again.